Is there a significant Iranian component to Ashkenazi Jewish genetics or not?
In the study The Origins of Ashkenaz, Ashkenazic Jews, and Yiddish, 467 modern Ashkenazi Jews were compared with ancient individuals from Eastern Europe, Anatolia, the Levant, and Iran using a supervised admixture analysis. The results showed

AJs exhibit a dominant Iranian (88%) and residual Levantine (3%) ancestries

Later in the same study, using a different analysis tool, and I think with Levantines removed from the analysis, Ashkenazi Jews are discovered to be 46% Neolithic Anatolian, 32% Neolithic Iranian, and 22% Eastern European Hunter Gatherer.
However, the study Missing Link of Jewish European Ancestry: Contrasting the Rhineland and Khazarian Hypotheses shows a completely different result when an admixture analysis is performed with Near Eastern (with Turks and Iranians used as the reference population), and Middle Eastern (with Palestinians used as the reference population) and Eastern European Jews. The results, shown in figure 5, show a large (25%) Palestinian ancestry for Eastern European Jews, and a small (around 5%) Turkish and Iranian ancestry.
There is a major difference between the percentage of Iranian ancestry in the three analyses (88%, 32%, and 5%) and the percentage of Levantine ancestry between the first and third (3% and 25%) respectively. Do Ashkenazi Jews have a high percentage of Iranian ancestry and a low percentage of Levantine ancestry as shown in the two analyses in the first study, or a high percentage of Levantine ancestry and a low percentage of Iranian ancestry, and are these results in conflict with each other, or is there something I am not understanding.

When after a great deal of debate people close your question, the proper response is not to rehash it and immediately repost it.

Especially with a link that malfunctions {https: repeated 3 times}. Had you thought of taking a look at our [biology.se] or even [bioinformatics.se], sites? The latter regarding data sets - then we've a [statistics.se] (statistics) site to help with the analysis.

Is this a different question to https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/57555/are-ashkenazi-jews-genetically-most-similar-to-italians-greeks-turks-and-arme - Im having a hard time determining if youve just changed the title to look different or if its actually a different question.

Strip away the political implications, and this is really just a question about whether a particular scientific method is reliable, and whether these particular studies were done well. Research not being reproducible isn't unusual, and is why things like meta-analyses exist.

@IMSoP - And there was yet another study, I think based on remains, that found both Palestinians and Iranian Jews to be very related to ancient Canaanite populations. I suspect what we are seeing here is the importance of definitions of "relatedness," and perhaps the difficulty or impossibility of fully disentangling e.g. Turkish descent from Iranian from Palestinian as the authors might like to do.

@IMSoP - Though I would point out that historiographical evidence should make us a priori pretty skeptical of a claim of around 90% Iranian descent for European Jewish populations. There's evidence of spread of the Jewish diaspora starting from the Roman Empire through Europe, which would support various degrees of Judean and European descent, without much room for almost entirely Iranian descent.

@Obie2.0 - Indeed, the exact results in the 2016 study seem to vary depending the analysis method used. The first method got 88% Iranian for Ashkenazi Jews, and the second method got 32% Iranian for Ashkenazi Jews, with the Anatolian percentage being even higher than the Iranian percentage in the analysis using the second method.
